# Auth0 and Vue.js. Redirect to previous page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, auth0

I am using `auth0` to handle the Login in my `Vue.js` app.

I wrote an `AuthService`, where I handle all the `auth0` stuff. In the `constructor`, I create a new `auth0` `object`. Then I set the `redirectUrl` (https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11/configuration#redirecturl-string-) to a default location, where I would like to get redirected:

```
import auth0 from 'auth0-js';

class AuthService {
  constructor() {
    this.auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
      domain: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
      clientID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENTID,
      audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
      responseType: process.env.AUTH0_RESPONSE_TYPE,
      scope: process.env.AUTH0_SCOPE,
      redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/examplepage'
    });
}
```

So the login works, but I don't get redirected to my defined location, It stays at `http://localhost:8080`. I expected the redirect automatically after the successfull login. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to change `redirectUrl:` to `redirectUri:`

Also if you have not already, in your Auth0 account, you need to add the Url to your `Allowed Callback URLs`  https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vanillajs/01-login#configure-callback-urls

There seems to be an inconsistency in their naming convention, or perhaps for some reason it is purposeful.  The docs you address are for "Lock for Web" and it does have "redirectUrl" but in the "auth0.WebAuth" parameters it uses `redirectUri`   https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js  and https://auth0.com/docs/users/guides/redirect-users-after-login

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Since I have to set the `url` in the Application Settings, which are allowed, this will not be the solution I'm looking for. I have to solve it by saving my last location and change it when login. Thanks anyway.